# Mouse/trackpad acceleration settings reset after suspend on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, mouse, touchpad, suspend, trackpad

There is no GUI option in Ubuntu 14.04 to change mouse acceleration, so I'm changing it via the xset command in a startup script in /etc/xdg/autostart/

However, after waking the system from suspend this option reverts to the (unusably slow) default. Any idea how to fix it?